PHP 2D array finding values by certain criteria
Each item of PHP 2D array $g contains

ID in index 0,
delay in index 5,
binary in index 6,
category in index 7,
weight in index 8

For each ID show cat for binary 1 having highest delay along with weight and category for binary 0 having highest delay along with weight.
If multiple categories have delay within 60 between each other, chose the one where weight for binary 0 and 1 for the same category and delay are closest to each other. The categories shown for 0 and 1 must be the same.
Example data
<?php

$g[0]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','aB3cD','14','0','38','160','1');
$g[1]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','eF4gH','14','0','40','169','1');
$g[2]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','J7kLm','14','0','42','182','1');
$g[3]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','N8oPq','14','0','44','199','1');
$g[4]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','R1sTu','14','0','46','217','1');
$g[5]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','vW9xY','14','0','48','237','1');
$g[6]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','zZ2aB','14','0','50','252','1');
$g[7]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','6C7dE','25056','0','38','157','1');
$g[8]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','fG8hI','25056','0','42','177','1');
$g[9]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','L3mNo','25056','0','44','193','1');
$g[10]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','pQ4rS','25056','0','46','210','1');
$g[11]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','T5uVw','25056','0','48','229','1');
$g[12]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','xY6zA','25056','0','50','244','1');
$g[13]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','B7cDe','25057','0','40','165','1');
$g[14]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','F9gHj','14','1','38','235','1');
$g[15]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','Q2rSt','14','1','40','219','1');
$g[16]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','V4wXy','14','1','42','201','1');
$g[17]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','Z5aBc','14','1','44','184','1');
$g[18]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','gH6iJ','14','1','46','170','1');
$g[19]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','kL7mN','14','1','48','159','1');
$g[20]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','oP8qR','14','1','50','153','1');
$g[21]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','rS9tU','25056','1','38','242','1');
$g[22]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','vW1xY','25056','1','42','207','1');
$g[23]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','zX2aB','25056','1','44','189','1');
$g[24]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','D3eFg','25056','1','46','175','1');
$g[25]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','E4fGh','25056','1','48','163','1');
$g[26]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','F5gHi','25056','1','50','156','1');
$g[27]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','G6hIj','25057','1','40','226','1');
$g[28]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','H7jK8','23734','0','58','224','1');
$g[29]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','I8kL9','23734','0','60','251','1');
$g[30]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','J9lM0','23792','0','54','195','1');
$g[31]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','K0mN1','25057','0','48','156','1');
$g[32]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','L1nO2','25057','0','50','167','1');
$g[33]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','M2oP3','25057','0','52','179','1');
$g[34]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','N3pQ4','25057','0','54','194','1');
$g[35]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','O4qR5','25057','0','56','210','1');
$g[36]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','P5rS6','25057','0','58','224','1');
$g[37]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','Q6sT7','25057','0','60','251','1');
$g[38]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','R7tU8','24938','1','48','243','1');
$g[39]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','S8uV9','24938','1','52','204','1');
$g[40]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','T9vW0','24938','1','54','187','1');
$g[41]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','U0wX1','25057','1','48','244','1');
$g[42]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','V1xY2','25057','1','50','222','1');
$g[43]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','W2yZ3','25057','1','52','205','1');
$g[44]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','X3zA4','25057','1','54','188','1');
$g[45]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','Y4aB5','25057','1','56','175','1');
$g[46]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','Z5bC6','25057','1','58','166','1');
$g[47]=array('18573','1713654000','755','745','a6C7d','25057','1','60','153','1');
$g[48]=array('18574','1713657600','749','817','b8D9e','28656','0','32','149','1');
$g[49]=array('18574','1713657600','749','817','c9E0f','28656','0','34','161','1');
$g[50]=array('18574','1713657600','749','817','d0F1g','28656','0','36','173','1');
$g[51]=array('18574','1713657600','749','817','e1G2h','28656','0','38','191','1');
$g[52]=array('18574','1713657600','749','817','f2H3i','28656','0','40','206','1');
$g[53]=array('18574','1713657600','749','817','g3I4j','28656','0','42','221','1');
$g[54]=array('18574','1713657600','749','817','h4J5k','28656','0','44','250','1');
$g[55]=array('18574','1713657600','749','817','i5K6l','28656','1','32','262','1');

The code below works well for highest delay, but for lowest returns the same. How should I modify the code to work correctly for lowest as well? E. g. for the ID 18572 the output should be Lowest Delay: cat: 44, Outcome 0: 184, Outcome 1: 199, Delay: 14

$g = array ( /* see example data above */);
$groupedById = [];

foreach ($g as $entry) {
    $id = $entry[0];
    if (!isset($groupedById[$id])) {
        $groupedById[$id] = [];
    }
    $groupedById[$id][] = $entry;
}

foreach ($groupedById as $id => $entries) {
    $bin0 = [];
    $bin1 = [];

    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        if ($entry[6] == '0') {
            $bin0[] = $entry;
        } elseif ($entry[6] == '1') {
            $bin1[] = $entry;
        }
    }

    usort($bin0, fn($a, $b) => $b[5] - $a[5]);
    usort($bin1, fn($a, $b) => $b[5] - $a[5]);

    $highest = getBestMatch($bin0, $bin1);
    $lowest = getBestMatch(array_reverse($bin0), array_reverse($bin1));

    echo "ID: $id\n";
    echo "Highest Delay:\n";
    echo "cat: {$highest['cat']}, Bin 0: {$highest['$w0']}, Bin 1: {$highest['$w1']}, Delay: {$highest['delay']}\n";
    echo "Lowest Delay:\n";
    echo "cat: {$lowest['cat']}, Bin 0: {$lowest['$w0']}, Bin 1: {$lowest['$w1']}, Delay: {$lowest['delay']}\n";
}

function getBestMatch($bin0, $bin1) {
    $bestMatch = null;
    $minwDiff = PHP_INT_MAX;

    foreach ($bin0 as $o0) {
        foreach ($bin1 as $o1) {
            if ($o0[7] == $o1[7] && abs($o0[5] - $o1[5]) <= 60) {
                $wDiff = abs($o0[8] - $o1[8]);
                if ($wDiff < $minwDiff) {
                    $minwDiff = $wDiff;
                    $bestMatch = [
                        'cat' => $o0[7],
                        '$w0' => $o0[8],
                        '$w1' => $o1[8],
                        'delay' => max($o0[5], $o1[5]),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $bestMatch;
}

?>



Is this a minimal [mcve]?

For each ID show cat for binary 1 having highest delay along with weight and category for binary 0 having highest delay along with weight. They are all highest anyway?

e.g. for ID 18572 values 25056/7 are highest and 14 are lowest

@reader54 I think what 'shingo yesterday' meant by his comment is, that you have a mistake in your sentence: 'category for binary 0 having highest delay'. Shouldn't this rather be: 'category for binary 0 having lowest delay'?

you just have to duplicate min max (one ascending, another descending) and teach the function about getting the max or the min:
// Step 1: Group by ID
foreach ($g as $entry) {
    $id = $entry[0];
    if (!isset($groupedById[$id])) {
        $groupedById[$id] = [];
    }
    $groupedById[$id][] = $entry;
}

// Step 2: Process each ID
foreach ($groupedById as $id => $entries) {
    $bin0 = [];
    $bin1 = [];

    // Separate entries by binary value (index 6)
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        if ($entry[6] == '0') {
            $bin0[] = $entry;
        } elseif ($entry[6] == '1') {
            $bin1[] = $entry;
        }
    }

    // Step 3: Find the best match for highest delay
    $highest = findBestMatch($bin0, $bin1, 'max');
    
    // Step 4: Find the best match for lowest delay
    $lowest = findBestMatch($bin0, $bin1, 'min');

    // Step 5: Output results
    echo "ID: $id</br>";
    echo "Highest Delay:</br>";
    echo "cat: {$highest['cat']}, Bin 0: {$highest['w0']}, Bin 1: {$highest['w1']}, Delay: {$highest['delay']}</br>";
    echo "Lowest Delay:</br>";
    echo "cat: {$lowest['cat']}, Bin 0: {$lowest['w0']}, Bin 1: {$lowest['w1']}, Delay: {$lowest['delay']}</br>";
}

// Function to find the best match
function findBestMatch($bin0, $bin1, $mode) {
    $bestMatch = null;
    $minwDiff = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $bestDelay = $mode === 'max' ? PHP_INT_MIN : PHP_INT_MAX;

    foreach ($bin0 as $o0) {
        foreach ($bin1 as $o1) {
            if ($o0[7] == $o1[7] && abs($o0[5] - $o1[5]) <= 60) {  // Same category and delay difference <= 60
                $wDiff = abs($o0[8] - $o1[8]);

                // Determine if the delay matches the criteria (highest or lowest)
                if (($mode === 'max' && max($o0[5], $o1[5]) > $bestDelay) ||
                    ($mode === 'min' && min($o0[5], $o1[5]) < $bestDelay) ||
                    ($bestDelay === max($o0[5], $o1[5]) && $wDiff < $minwDiff)) {
                    $bestDelay = $mode === 'max' ? max($o0[5], $o1[5]) : min($o0[5], $o1[5]);
                    $minwDiff = $wDiff;

                    $bestMatch = [
                        'cat' => $o0[7],
                        'w0' => $o0[8],
                        'w1' => $o1[8],
                        'delay' => $bestDelay,
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $bestMatch;
}


There seems to be something incorrect, because e.g. for ID 18572 the answer for highest should be
cat: 44, Bin 0: 193, Bin 1: 184, Delay: 25056

No. I research your array and find that this is the row that contains the highest for ID 18572.
$g[27]=array('18572','1713654000','751','759','G6hIj','25057','1','40','226','1');

yes, but there is the allowed "error" of 60 If multiple categories have delay within 60 between each other, choose the one where weight for binary 0 and 1 for the same category and delay are closest to each other.

Do you mean that the highest and the lowest should be extracted for the same category?

I got you now. I solved the lowest and highest for you. Now you should be able to adjust the code yourself to check for the allowed error. If you can't write me here, and I'll help you again.

Thanks, it seems to be working! I just added +-60 to $bestDelay in the condition
